# PowerCLI Can't add update to previously created baseline

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to programatically get the latest VMware tools update and add it to an already created baseline in powershell, however running this command directly in powershell does work as intended it adds the update correctly, but in the automated script the same code doesn't add the update as running the command in the powershell command line.

this is the code:

```
$latest_tools = Get-Patch | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*VMware Tools*"}| Sort-Object -Property Version | Select-Object -Last 1

Set-PatchBaseline -Baseline $baseline -IncludePatch $latest_tools
```

I noted that when creating a new baseline there is a property Static/Dynamic, i have tried with both and none of them are working as expected.
I need to add some additonal configuration?

Comment: Since the code it self works, maybe you should post the automated script it self with some debugging output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason in powershell sorting by default gives the descending order, but in ansible you have to give explicit order like this:

> $latest_tools = Get-Patch | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*VMware
> Tools*"}| Sort-Object -Property Version **-Descending** |
> Select-Object -Last 1

Answer (score 1):

If this (using [`Set-PatchBaseline`](https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/cc21bbd6-8045-4b27-a0f7-1a2482cbbed9/30172ff5-e1ca-49fa-9614-43801b231cdc/doc/index.html)) works in an interactive session but not in an automated script, make sure that:

- the automated script and the interactive session are running with the same credentials and environment settings.
- the `$baseline` variable is correctly populated and scoped in the automated script, and is actually retrieving the correct baseline object.
- `$latest_tools` is valid and contains the correct patch details, especially when running in an automated context.
- the object stored in `$latest_tools` is compatible with the `Patch[]` type expected by the `-IncludePatch` parameter.
- any possible error is captured

```
Try {
    $baseline = Get-PatchBaseline -Name "Your Baseline Name"
    $latest_tools = Get-Patch | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*VMware Tools*"} | Sort-Object -Property Version | Select-Object -Last 1
    Set-PatchBaseline -Baseline $baseline -IncludePatch $latest_tools -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose
}
Catch {
    Write-Host "An error occurred: $_"
}
```

That should help you detecting any issue with the script.